# VsVim - vit and vat not working correctly

Tags: html, xaml, vim, visual-studio-2017, vsvim

I am using the VsVim plugin with Visual Studio 2017. I do a lot of XAML/HTML editing and recently read that the vit / vat commands can select content between tags. However, when the tag definition extends over multiple lines, this does not seem to work.

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid"
      Width="10"
      Height="10"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
...
...
...
</Grid> <!-- vit/vat will not work for me here -->
```

Any insight on how to do this properly? I may not even be using the right commands for this task.

Comment: Quick comment: The suggested grid is not necessarily the root parent of the UserControl/Window.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen in this scenario?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I was on vacation overseas. I am expecting all content between the Grid tag to be visually selected with the vit command. For vat, I am expecting all content including the tags to be selected.